How can I compare two HashMaps for object identity, NOT value identity?
I want to compare two Hashmaps that are different although their contained objects are the same.  I want to be able to tell when they are different.  How can I test their underlying object identity is different ?

fn main(){
    let h1 = HashMap::<i64,i64>::new();
    let h2 = HashMap::<i64,i64>::new();
    
    assert!(h1 != h2);  // this doesn't work, the maps have identical collections.
}



Since Rust only allows one owner per value, that kind of comparison will always be inequal.
If you want to compare two references to HashMaps, you can use std::ptr::eq:
assert!(!std::ptr::eq(&h1, &h2));

Also check out the related function addr_eq, or for Arc and Rc, there is ptr_eq.
